# How to add element to artboard without moving it in Figma?

Tags: artboard, figma

While working with [Figma](http://www.figma.com), I often end up with elements that are in the right place, but not inside the artboard they are supposed to be in.

Is there an easy trick to put the element into the underlying artboard without moving it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best solution here is to drag the layer or group manually into the artboard in the layer menu.
The layer should keep his original positioning but is now inside the artboard:

[image: Drag Layer to Artboard]

Comment: This does work, but it's pretty hard when you're working with a lot of layers and artboards. I hoped there was an easy shortcut like "put into underlying artboard". Oh well. Accepted until there is a better solution.

Comment: Totally understand that. Personally I dont have this kind of problem, because I rename / group / order each layer right after its creation. First to draw everything on the canvas and then trying to clean everything up is a total mess no matter which software you use.